# Create column with value one year later for every group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm working with a DataFrame with the following format:

```
id    Period    value
 1    201308      A
 1    201309      A
         .
 1    201408      C
 1    201409      D
         .
         .
 2    201308      B
 2    201309      C
         .
 2    201408      A
 2    201409      B
```

And I want to create a column `value_t1` that has the value a year later i.e. for `Period+100`. I managed to do it, but in a very inefficient way:

```
aux = df[['Period','value','id']].copy()
aux.rename(columns={'Period':'Period_t1','value':'value_t1'}, inplace=True)
df['Period_t1']=df.Period+100
df = df.merge(aux, on=['Period_t1','id'])
```

Which brings:

```
id    Period    value  Period_t1  value_t1
 1    201308      A     201408       C
 1    201309      A     201409       D
         .
         .
 2    201308      B     201408       A
 2    201309      C     201409       B
         .
         .
```

Which is what I need (the column `Period_t1` isn't needed). I feel there has to be a more efficient 1 or 2 liner, probably using `shift()`. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your solution is very similar to mine. Why is it *very inefficient*?

Comment: merging doesn't seem like the best option when I'm retrieving data from the same dataset

Comment: It just naturally looks like a merge problem. You can certainly `set_index(['id', 'Period'])` and use `loc` access. But that would raise error when the future date is not available.

Comment: Check my answer, I finally managed to achieve what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it better, it was easier than expected:

```
df['value_t1'] = df.groupby(['id']).value.shift(-12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['Period_'] = df['Period'] + 100

(df.merge(df.drop('Period_', axis=1), 
          left_on=['id','Period_'],
          right_on=['id','Period'],
          suffixes=['','_t1'])
  .drop('Period_', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
   id  Period value  Period_t1 value_t1
0   1  201308     A     201408        C
1   1  201309     A     201409        D
2   2  201308     B     201408        A
3   2  201309     C     201409        B
```